# Difference between HDF and Apache NiFi

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I am trying to understand difference between Apache Nifi and Hortonworks Data Flow (HDF).

How they differ from each other in terms of capability and overall design ? What will be possible use cases for Nifi and HDF ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hortonworks Data Flow (HDF) is a platform for data collection, curation, analysis, and delivery. It is made up of Apache NiFi, Apache Kafka, Apache Storm, and Apache Ranger. You can read more about it here: https://hortonworks.com/products/data-center/hdf/

Apache NiFi is an open-source data flow tool, and is one of the tools included in HDF.

Comment: From architecture point of view , Does HDF needs to be installed  on different server other than HDP  ? So that HDF can talk to HDP cluster.

Comment: For a production deployment, HDF services should not be installed on the same servers as HDP services, but the servers do need to be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: @BryanBende : In the recent HDF (3.0.1.1) version the NiFi version is 1.2, Can I upgrade the NiFi version to 1.4 in the HDF? Or should I wait for HDF to roll out an update that has NiFi with 1.4 version?

Comment: HDF 3.0.1.1 is actually closest to Apache NiFi 1.3.0. For HDF it is best to wait for the next official HDF release to get the NiFi updates.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. Wanted to use the Process Group Variables in NiFi 1.4 version. So seems like the best thing to do is to wait until HDF release the new version.